# Regex - Match escape characters inside attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

Well, I'm not an expert with regex.

My problem is simple, Im trying to match some escape characters from a string which have this format (It is a string before I parse it to a DOM)

```
<info type="map" name="Double quotes test name" author="Escape < character"></info>
<info type="map" name='Test name with single quotes' author='Escape < character'></info>
```

As you can see, there are 2 types of properties that I'm trying to match, these are name and author.
I want to convert `<` character to `&lt`, however, my patter is not matching properly.

My pattern currently match the whole attribute value. It even matches attributes which aren't author or name.

```
/(?!author|name\s*=\s*)(?:\'[^']*\')/g
```

I hope you can bring me a hand with this, thanks for reading and best regards.

Comment: Where do you get this string from? Fix at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try matching all `<` that are not preceeded by either newline, start of string or `>`:

```
(?<=[^\n>])<
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/sTbjQT/1).

---

If you want to make sure the `<` is found within the value of either the name or author attribute, you can use:

```
(?<=(?:author|name)=(?:"[^<"]+?|'[^<']+?))<
```

where the `<` is preceeded by:

- `(?:author|name)`: either "author" or "name" keyword
- `=`: equals
- `(?:"[^<"]+?|'[^<']+?)`:

  - `"[^<"]+?`: a `"` followed by least amount of characters which don't include `"` and `<`
  - `|`: or
  - `'[^<']+?`: a `'` followed by least amount of characters which don't include `'` and `<`

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/cPSc1Y/1).

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I could match directly the escape character, however, I wanted to know how can I add support for only matching value inside the attributes previously mentioned. `Why do I ask this ?` Well, I want to replace this character in another language where `<` character is not considered as escaped, however, would be a great way to learn how to only affect these 2 attributes. Thanks newly.

Comment: Something can be done for the author attribute. Although it looks like there's no `<` in the value of the name attribute. Why do you want to match it as well?

Comment: `(?<=[^\n>])<` is leaner than `(?<!\n|^|>)<`.

Comment: @lemon Well, basically I want to match it due to I'm implementing this to a file uploader which reads an xml file. These xml files can containt attributes with any values added by the user. I have already seen `<, &, > ` If this occurs, I can't parse the data to a DOM. So, the process to upload the file due to other conditions, fails ...

Comment: Hopefully the second part of the updated answer can capture that as well.

Comment: @lemon Yep, thank you so much it works perfectly good. Thats what I looked for. I just added the rest of escape possibilities between brackets (I assume that this is the right way to do it, at least it worked in regex website) `(?<=(?:author|name)=(?:"[^<"]+?|'[^<']+?))[<|>|&]` Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew aswell, any help is over welcomed. Best regards guys.